# Filtering warnings with xlint

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse my team has specific rules for filtering java warnings.  For instance, we like to see warnings about "Non-static access to static members", but not "Indirect access to static members".

I would like to incorporate our filter into a gradle script, presumably via the Xlint flag.  However, [I only see broad categories](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#xlintwarnings) of warnings that I may enable/disable.  How can I map our eclipse rules to compiler arguments?